# Toolkit Transition service navigation in transition

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, button, windows-phone-8, toolkit

```
toolkit:TiltEffect.IsTiltEnabled="True"
```

Hi, I have a lot of buttons, but I want to set one of those not moving. Any idea how to set on those button like `toolkit:TiltEffect.IsTiltEnabled="false"`

Comment: Did you try the `suppress tilt` property?

Comment: @KarthikNishanth no, can you explain it?

Comment: `SuppressTilt`  
       This is a static dependency property of type bool that suppresses the tilt effect on a single control that would otherwise be tilted.